How do you communicate with atc and how can they communicate with you when you change frequency?
How do you let atc know that you are going to a different frequency and how will you be able to talk to them if they need to talk to you will they go to that frequency that you went to?


How do you let atc know that you are going to a different frequency

I can't speak about NZ-specific, but in general one of two things happen:

You ask/tell the current station you're in communication with that you wish to/are changing frequency
The station you're currently in communication with hand you off to another controller.

In the UK, this communication goes something like this:
For 1) above
G-ABCD: G-ABCD, request frequency change to [other station] [frequency]
ATC: G-ABCD squawk 7000, frequency change approved
G-ABCD: squawk 7000. G-ABCD

For 2)
ATC: G-ABCD, report your squawk to [other station] on [other frequency]
G-ABCD: Report squawk to [other frequency]

or, on reaching the limits of radar coverage.
ATC: G-ABCD you're reaching the limit of my coverage, traffic service terminates. squawk 7000, freecall [other station]
G-ABCD: squawk 7000, freecall en route. G-ABCD.


how will you be able to talk to them if they need to talk to you will they go to that frequency that you went to

Short answer: You can't and they can't. Once you're no longer on their frequency they can't talk to you.
Slightly longer answer: Occasionally, one controller is working more than one frequency. Quite often I hear something similar to 2) above (where I know from experience it's one controller working 2 radar frequencies) along the lines of "Report your squawk back to me on 125.250". In this case it's 2 radar zones, both provided by Farnborough radar - known as "Farnborough Radar North"  and "Farnborough Radar West".
Controllers at different stations can use the telephone to communicate with each to facilitate/orchestrate hand offs. I suppose if they needed to get back in contact with you, they could phone the station and ask that controller to pass you a message.

I don't have experience with New Zealand systems, only usa, but my guess is that this is the same in New Zealand as it is in America. (I could be mistaken.)
Pilot radios are designed to be user-tunable over the entire aviation frequency spectrum. ATC radios are not. Each frequency used by a facility will have its own dedicated receiver, transmitter, and antenna—and in most cases two of each, a "main" set and a "standby" set.
ATC can only select from the preset list of frequencies used at their facility—we don't have the ability to tune an arbitrary frequency, at least not on our normal equipment. We do have portable emergency radios that can be tuned to any frequency but their range is quite limited.
So to answer your second question: unless you have two radios and you can listen to both at once, ATC can only communicate with you if you remain on your assigned frequency.
